# Jquery inner UL FadeIn / FadeOut

Tags: jquery, menu, fadein, fadeout

I'm trying to accomplish a simple thing.
I have a 2 levels menu with nested ULs.
The inner ULs are set as display:none, so only the main categories are shown.
I would like to preventDefault onclick behaviour on the main categories and fade in their respective inner ULs aside.

My html is this:

```
<nav id="type-navigation">
    <ul id="nav_categories" class="subs">
        <li><a href="#">Category 1</a>
                <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
                </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Category 2</a>
                <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
                </ul>
        </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

I would like to do this using Jquery. When I click on the first category, its children UL should be shown aside with FadeIn. When I click on another category, the previously shown UL should FadeOut and the other categories UL should FadeIn.

This is my Jquery and it's not working as expected:

```
$("ul li a").toggle(function() { 
                  $(this).children("ul").fadeIn("slow");
                  },
                   function() { 
                 $(this).children("ul").fadeOut("slow"); 
                });
```

Comment: What does it do now? What should be different?

Comment: First of all, when I click on the first category link it goes to the resource… in the example there's no link really, just a #.
The fact is that the above menu is dinamically generated and all the # are in fact a link to /products/category, the first level also… I have to disable somehow with preventDefault the first category links to go to the link but just to activate the fadein

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your `<ul>` next to your `<a>` are hidden with css `display:none` :

```
$(".subs > li > a").click(function() {
    $(this).parents('.subs').find('ul').hide();
    if($(this).next("ul").is(":visible")) {
            $(this).next("ul").fadeOut("slow");
    }    else {
        $(this).next("ul").fadeIn("slow");
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: This made it work. In order to preventDefault just the first category a i had to write also 
$("ul#nav_categories > li > a").click(function(event){   
    event.preventDefault();
 });

Answer (score 2):

Try [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/f6Xy6/).

CSS from example:

```
nav > ul > li > ul {
 display:none;   
}​
```

jQuery from example:

```
$( 'ul#nav_categories > li > a' ).click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    theClickedLi = $( this );
    $( '#nav_categories' ).find( 'ul' ).fadeOut();
    theClickedLi.parent('li').find( 'ul' ).fadeIn();
} );
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Tats_innit thanks bro. But it looks like Thomas' answer satisfied the OP.

Comment: No worries, Yep & you have a nice answer as well :) have a nice one!, cheers!

Comment: Thanks guys. Glad I could help. Just choose the answer that soothes your needs. Cheers.

Comment: I just posted a new question in case you want to help :)